# Unsupported config option for services.*: 'volumes_from'

Tags: docker, docker-compose

From this guide: https://olex.biz/2019/09/hosting-with-docker-nginx-reverse-proxy-letsencrypt/

I have the following file:

**docker-compose.yml**

```
version: '2'

services:
  nginx-proxy:
    image: jwilder/nginx-proxy
    container_name: nginx-proxy
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - conf:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - vhost:/etc/nginx/vhost.d
      - dhparam:/etc/nginx/dhparam
      - certs:/etc/nginx/certs:ro
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/tmp/docker.sock:ro
    networks:
      - proxy
    restart: always

  letsencrypt:
    image: jrcs/letsencrypt-nginx-proxy-companion
    container_name: nginx-proxy-le
    volumes_from:
      - nginx-proxy
    volumes:
      - certs:/etc/nginx/certs:rw
      - /var/run/docker.sock:/var/run/docker.sock:ro
    restart: always

volumes:
  conf:
  vhost:
  dhparam:
  certs:

networks:
  proxy:
    external:
      name: nginx-proxy
```

If I change on the very top of the file: `version: '2'` to: `version: '3'`, then I get the following error:

```
ERROR: The Compose file './docker-compose.yml' is invalid because:
Unsupported config option for services.letsencrypt: 'volumes_from'
```

Could you let me know the necessary transformations to do in order for this to work with: `version: '3'`?

Thanks!

Comment: docker-compose >3 made volumes_from obsolete because you define the volumes globally and inject them into each service.

Comment: yes, but then, what would be the resulting `docker-compose.yml` file?

Comment: Did you finally found the answer to this question?